# Add prefix to multiple consecutive git commit message via script

Tags: git

I want to write a bash script that changes the commit message of a series of consecutive commits as follows:

```
bash rename-git-messages.sh $sha_start $sha_end "my-prefix-"
```

the output should look like this

```
my-prefix-old message1
my-prefix-old message2
...
```

My current (tedious) solution is to do an interactive rebase on $sha_start and change every "pick" in the rebase config file to "rename". However, like this I'm still asked for every commit, how I want to change the commit message...

Answer (score 1):

Git allows you to use different editors for the sequence editor (that is, the one that interactive rebase uses) and the default editor (which will be used to edit commit messages).  If a sequence editor is not specified, Git will use the regular editor.

Both of those editors are passed to the shell, so you can use shell scripts here.  There are a couple of options to use for editing the commands.

First, there's `sed`.  You want an in-place edit, which requires the `-i` argument.  Using the GNU tools (on Linux or Git Bash), that looks like this:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e 's/pick/reword/'" \
GIT_EDITOR="sed -i -e '1s/^/my-prefix-/'" \
git rebase -i $sha_start
```

However, on macOS, `-i` always requires an argument, so it will look like this:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i '' -e 's/pick/reword/'" \
GIT_EDITOR="sed -i '' -e '1s/^/my-prefix-/'" \
git rebase -i $sha_start
```

If this is inconvenient because you'd like to write portable code (who wouldn't?), you can use Perl:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="perl -pi -e 's/pick/reword/'" \
GIT_EDITOR="perl -pi -e 's/^/my-prefix-/' if $. == 1'" \
git rebase -i $sha_start
```

This is also possible with Ruby if you don't care for Perl:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="ruby -pi -e '$_.gsub!(/pick/, %Q[reword])'" \
GIT_EDITOR="ruby -pi -e '$_.gsub!(/^/, %Q[my-prefix-]) if $. == 1'" \
git rebase -i $sha_start
```

In general, all of these mark all the commits as "reword" in the sequence editing step, and then each commit is edited to include the prefix.  Other possibilities for editing include `ed` and `ex` (the colon commands for `vi`).

Answer (score 1):

Variant 1: using [`git filter-branch --msg-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt---msg-filterltcommandgt):

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter 'sed "s/^/my-prefix-old /"' $sha_start..
```

> the filter for rewriting the commit messages. The argument is evaluated in the shell with the original commit message on standard input; its standard output is used as the new commit message.

So I use `sed` to instantly change every line of every message.

`git filter-branch` doesn't support commit ranges, it can only be applied from a commit to `@` (`HEAD`).

Variant 2: using [`git filter-repo --replace-message`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-use-it):

```
echo 'regex:^==>my-prefix-old ' >../replace-msg.txt
git filter-repo --replace-message ../replace-msg.txt --refs $sha_start..$sha_end
rm ../replace-msg.txt
```

Variant 3: using `git filter-repo --message-callback`:

```
git-filter-repo --message-callback 'return b"my-prefix-old " + message' --refs $sha_start..$sha_end
```

Though range `$sha_start..$sha_end` should work with `--refs` they don't work for me; `$sha_start..` work.